# I want to use loop in regular expression to increase the reg ex everytime is search match and add this match in new array

Tags: arrays, regex, perl, for-loop

I have an array as @versions with various versions ex- 6.1.1.1; 6.2.22.123; 2.12.1.123; 2.1.11.11, etc.
I have to make classes of all these specific format versions like- An array with version whose format is 1.1.1.1, 1.1.11.1, 1.1.1.111 and so on

My code is:

```
my @version1=(); 
foreach my $values (@versions)
{
    if( $values=~ /(.?[0-9]{1}.[0-9]{1}.[0-9]{1}.[0-9]{1}$)/)  # Regular expression to find version ex-1.1.1.1 at the end of the line($).
    {
        push (@version1,$values);
    }
};
print   "Version1 values are: @version1\n";

my @version2=();
foreach my $values (@versions)
{
    if( $values=~ /(.?[0-9]{1}.[0-9]{1}.[0-9]{1}.[0-9]{2}$)/) # Regular expression to find version ex-1.1.1.11 at the end of the line($).
    {
        push (@version2,$values);
    }
};
#print   "Version2 values are: @version2\n";
```

It gives me the result but I cannot create so many regular expression, so I need to use looping.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `+` quantifier to mean 1 or more digits:

```
/(.?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$)/
```